# Brisk walking vs Brisk walking at home (in place)

Tags: exercise, cardio, health

I think some recommendations say that in order to get health benefits (e.g. have lower risk of some possible health issues in the future) one should do

> "do at least 150 minutes of moderate intensity activity a week or 75
> minutes of vigorous intensity activity a week".

I did some research and I think doing a **brisk walk is considered average intensity activity**.

But for me to do brisk walk I would need to go far from home to a place where I can do brisk walk, so my question is, is there any difference if I do brisk walk at home vs brisk walk outside: By Brisk walk at home I mean imagine **you are standing on the same place but moving your legs at a faster pace, like you would do when walking, just you don't move forward.** So is there difference between such brisk walk and normal brisk walk in terms of above goal?

Comment: OP here: forgot to finalize account registration. I found exactly video describing the kind of brisk walk I mention: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlG_BQ2rBf0. So does this satisfy the minimum?

Comment: Other ways to determine the intensity of an exercise, https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/measuring/index.html https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/measuring/heartrate.htm